# QGIS Symbology: how to make a symbol a shape according to a set of rules and a color according to another set of rules

Tags: qgis, symbology, rule-based

I'm using QGIS 3.14 with GRASS 7.8.3. I have a data set with point coordinates on a plan (artifacts on an archaeological site). I have two main variables that I want to show. So, I'd like to have the type of artifacts as a letter (that I managed with the set of rules) and a color depending of the raw materials used for the artifact.

For example:

1. Biface, Chert
2. Biface, Quartz
3. Arrowhead, Jasper
4. Flake, Chert

I'd like to have all the bifaces with a B, and all the artifacts in chert showing up in grey. And that for all my categories (I have a dozen for each variable) and my data base includes hundreds of entries. I'd like a solution that is not too tedious if it possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To define the color, you can use the [categorized renderer](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#categorized-renderer) in layer styling. Choose the field where you have stored your material (in my case I named it simply `var2`) and set random colors (or any color ramp you like), then click classify. Now you have your symbol styled with diferent colors, one color for each material type.

[image]

Now configure (style) the symbol - click on the symbol above and in the opening symbol selector panel choose [Font marker](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/style_library/symbol_selector.html#marker-symbols). On the botton, you see a default font-symbol character (A) with the data-driven override symbol to the right: ​`ɛ`​. Click this and choose edit to open the expression editor. There, insert an expression that generates the Letter you want to use.

I created an expression that returns the firts letter of the field that defines the type of artifacts - in my case, I named the field just `var1`: `left("var1" ,1)`.

Explanation: With the expression `left()` you tell QGIS the select characters starting from the left of your input-string (your field for artifact type, replace `var1` with the field-name you use) and just select one character - increase the number the get more characters. If you apply these changes, you get something like this on my screenshot. I added a label on two separate lines that gives the content of the var1 (type of artifact) and `var2` (material) fields from the attribute table.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the clear and efficient answer. It's working. Thank you !!